# Исчезновение элемента при нажатии на контейнер

Tags: jquery

Мне нужно что-бы после нажатия на show можно было нажать на контейнер `.wrapper` (то есть за округами блока) и происходил эффект исчезновения, как при втором нажатии на show, кто знает как это сделать?

ВНИМАНИЕ ! нужно, чтобы этот триггер возможно было нажать после первого нажатия на show. То есть в скрытом состоянии, когда нажимаешь на `.wrapper` ничего не появляется.

**Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/37/**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $('#triggermap').click(function() {
        var map = $(".schememap");
        
        map.stop();
        
        if(map.is(':visible')) {
            map.animate({ right:493, opacity: 0 }, 1200, function() {
               $(this).hide().css('right', 0);
            });
        }
        else {
            map.show().animate({ right:193, opacity: 1 }, 1200);}     
    }); 
    
    
});
```

```css
.schememap {
    display: none;
    height: 234px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    right: 0;
    width: 500px;    
}
#triggermap {
 border-bottom: 1px dashed;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #0C5394;
 float: left;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <p id='triggermap'>show</p>
    <div class="schememap" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: округи квадрата - это 5. у вас клик висит на `#triggermap`, ну повесьте его на те элементы, которые нужны. например на `'.wrapper,.wrapper *'`.

Comment: у вас тут кружок "граммар наци гоу на!" ? реально, иногда кажется, что вопросы задают иностранные разведчики с какими-то своими целями.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ! буду изучать ваш код. Только не знаю как поставить вам правильный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ad8zr/38/

```js
$(function () {
    var map = $(".schememap");
    var $triggermap=$('#triggermap');
    var triggermap=$triggermap.get(0);
    function hide() {
        map.stop().animate({
            right: 493,
            opacity: 0
        }, 1200, function () {
            $(this).hide().css('right', 0);
        });

    }
   $('.wrapper').click(function (e){  
       console.log(e.target,triggermap);
       if (e.target === triggermap || e.target === map.get(0)) return;
        if (map.is(':visible')) {
            map.finish();
            hide();
        }
    });
    $triggermap.click(function () {

        map.finish();

        if (map.is(':visible')) {
            hide();
        } else {
            map.show().animate({
                right: 193,
                opacity: 1
            }, 1200);
        }
    });


});
```

```css
.schememap {
    display: none;
    height: 234px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    right: 0;
    width: 500px;
}
#triggermap {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #0C5394;
    float: left;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <p id='triggermap'>show</p>
    <div class="schememap"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Я знаю. Надо повесить обработчик нажатия на .wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

так повешай на событие click исчезновение того что тебе нужно. и все.
http://jsfiddle.net/6HuaB/